# Why there is no std::make_raw_storage_iterator?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering why `std::raw_storage_iterator` does not have an accompanying `std::make_raw_storage_iterator` like `std::move_iterator` and `std::make_move_iterator`. The `std::raw_storage_iterator` class template has two template parameters. So I think it is actually more useful to provide a make function for `std::raw_storage_iterator` than `std::move_iterator` which only has a single template parameter to specify.

Comment: @dyp Isn't the second argument deducible using `std::iterator_traits`?

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood how raw_storage_iterator works. Sorry.

Comment: Output iterators may have no useful information in `iterator_traits` but the iterator category. However, `T` could be deduced from the return type of `operator&` applied to the return type of `operator*` I think.

Comment: @dyp Interesting point. I think it actually answers the question to some degree.

Comment: @dyp `std::raw_storage_iterator` is a pre-C++11 thing. And without the `decltype` C++11 keyword, there seems no direct way to provide such a make function.

Comment: @dyp Ahh, alright. TIL. :)

Comment: @dyp I have an answer that stole your suggestion, can I post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @dyps suggestions, a sensible implementation is indeed possible:

```
template <typename OutputIt>
auto make_raw_storage_iterator( OutputIt out ) {
    return std::raw_storage_iterator<OutputIt, std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(&*out)>>(out);
}
```

([**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09bf337ea68ace62) with cppreference's example)
This is guaranteed to work since §20.7.10/1, which imposes requirements for the template arguments of `raw_storage_iterator`, mandates that:

> `OutputIterator` is required to have its `operator*` return an object for
>   which `operator&` is defined and returns a pointer to `T` [..]

Where `T` is the second argument, the value type of the output range. So, given the underlying output iterator, we have enough information to determine the intended specialization of `raw_storage_iterator`.

The reason this has not been proposed is assuredly not more than an oversight - consider that `make_reverse_iterator` or even `make_unique` have not been provided before C++14, either. Feel free to take the first step.

Comment: @dyp Wait, I just realizedsomething strange (I'm probably just being blind again). Is `OutputIterator` required to be a class by my quote? Or could that paragraph be referring to builtin `operator*`?

Comment: There seem to be several occurrences of `operator` (in the library part) that can include built-ins.

Comment: @dyp Yeah, apparently `operator*` is used for both member functions and the builtin ones, in other sections as well.

Comment: The requirement that `&` works looks like a defect. Compare [LWG 2433](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2433).